# If $x = 2\log_39 + \log_{27}5,$ then $3^x = ??$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-sum

If
$$x = 2\log_39 + \log_{27}5,$$
then $3^x = ??$

I know $2\log_39$ is $4$, however how do I find an exact answer to the whole equation??

I tried to change the base of the second one to $ 3 $, however it did not work out.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}x= 2\log_{3}9+\log_{27}5\\
=2\log_{3}9+{1\over3}\log_{3}5 \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}3^x=3^{[2\log_{3}9+1/3\log_{3}5]}&
&\\=3^{2\log_{3}9}3^{1/3\log_{3}5} 
&\\=9^{2\log_{3}3}5^{1/3\log_{3}3}
\\=9^{2}\cdot 5^{1/3}
\\=81\sqrt[3]5
\end{align}$$

> we use :
>
> $a^{\log(b)}=b^{\log(a)}$
>
> proof:
>
> Let :$ x = a^{\log(b)}$, and $y = b^{\log(a)}$
>
> $\log x = \log{(a^{\log(b)})} = \log(b)\log(a) $
>
> $\log y = \log{(b^{\log(a)})} = \log(a)\log(b) $
>
> $\log(a)\log(b) = \log(b)\log(a)$
>
> $ \log x = \log y$
>
> $x = y $

Comment: +1; use `\log x`$(\log x)$ instead of `log`$(log)$.

Comment: @A---B Thanks .

Comment: Check if my edit is ok or not.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\log_{27}5=\frac{\ln5}{\ln 27}=\frac{\ln 5}{3\ln 3}=\frac13\log_3 5$$

Answer (score 4):

You must write $\log_{27}(5) = \frac{\log_3(5)}{\log_3(27)} = \frac{\log_3(5)}{3} = \log_3(5^{1/3})$

Answer (score 3):

we write $$x=2\log_3 3^2+\frac{\ln(5)}{3\ln(3)}=4+\frac{1}{3}\log_3 5$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\log_{27} 5 = \frac{\log_3 5}{\log_{3} 27},$$ using the change of base formula $$\log_b x = \frac{\log_c x}{\log_c b}.$$  Now can you proceed?

---

Proof of the change of base formula:

Note that if there is a number $y$ such that $\log_b x = y$, then $b^y = x$.  Now taking base-$c$ logarithms of both sides, we get $$\log_c b^y = \log_c x.$$  Now the LHS can be written $\log_c b^y = y \log_c b$, hence $$y \log_c b = \log_c x,$$ therefore $$y = \frac{\log_c x}{\log_c b},$$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\log_{27}(5) = \frac{\log_3(5)}{\log_3(27)} = \frac{\log_3(5)}{3} = \log_3(5^{\frac{1}{3}})$.

Then $x = 2\log_3(9) + \log_{27}(5)  = \log_3(81) + \log_3(5^\frac{1}{3}) = \log_3(81 \cdot 5^{\frac{1}{3}})$.

You obtain that $3^x = 81 \cdot 5^\frac{1}{3}$.